# como subir las imagenes con la api de imgur a mi cuenta con python

Tags: python

estoy programando un bot para discord y tengo un problema y no se como subir una imagen a mi cuenta de imgur desde python, la forma en que lo hago se sube de forma anonima y asi no deberia, lo que intento esque se almacene las imagenes en mi cuenta de imgur

He leído la documentación pero no entiendo mucho, acabo de empezar a programar

Este es el código que estoy usando actualmente:

```
@bot.command()
async def imgur(ctx):
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Client-ID xxx',}
    params = {'image': base64.b64encode(open('cosmetico.png', 'rb').read())}
    r = requests.post(f'https://api.imgur.com/3/image', headers=headers, data=params)
    
    data = r.json()["data"]["link"]
   
await ctx.send(f"{data}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.-)Ingresar al siguiente link https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient

2.-) al presionar el boton enviar te llevara a otra pagina donde tendras que copiar **client_id**

copia el código te hara falta para obtener el token...

ingresa el client_id en el siguiente parametro:

```
https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=CLIENT ID AQUÍ&response_type=token
```

una vez añadido copia la url completa y la pegas en el navegador.

te aparecera otra pagina y le presionas al boton "ALLOW"

y arriba te aparecera una url larga copiala en el block de notas

y localiza el parametro: **access_token**

Copia el codigo largo

y lo añades en el código de python

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer AQUÍ EL ACESS TOKEN',}
```

Código completo:

de esta forma obtendras el hash para borrar la imagen y la url de imgur.. la imagen se alojara a tu cuenta de imgur

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import base64
 
 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") #Comando
bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help
 
 
@bot.command()
async def imgur(ctx):
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer AQUI PEGA EL ACCESS TOKEN',}
    params = {'image': base64.b64encode(open('cosmetico.png', 'rb').read())}
    r = requests.post(f'https://api.imgur.com/3/image', headers=headers, data=params)
    
    data = r.json()["data"]["link"]
    borrar = r.json()["data"]["deletehash"]
   
    await ctx.send(f"Link directo:\n```{data}```\nBBCode(Para foros):\n```[img]{data}[/img]```")
    await ctx.author.send(f"{borrar}")
 
 
 
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("BOT listo!")
    
 
    
bot.run('') #OBTEN UN TOKEN EN: https://discord.com/developers/applications
````

Para poder borrar la imagen subida a imgur es:

```
import requests

id_borrar = input("Escribe el codigo para borrar la imagen: ")
url = f"https://api.imgur.com/3/image/{id_borrar}"


payload={}
files={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer AQUI PEGA EL ACCESS TOKEN'
}

response = requests.request("DELETE", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias justamente lo que estaba buscando